# Using paper.js and p5.js in same Sublime Text window

Tags: javascript, paperjs, p5.js

I am trying to show my works on a website using p5.js and paper.js.

Can I use two different JavaScript libraries in same Sublime Text HTML window?

Comment: This question is hard to understand. Sublime text is just an editor.  What is the outcome you want to achieve?  What have you attempted so far?

Comment: What prevents you from adding two <script/> tags in your html page?or are you talking  about using these libs with sublime intellisense etc?

Comment: can you please add some specific details or clarify the question in order for us to give answers correctly..? maybe you can explain to us what is this `Sublime Text HTML window`? I'm assuming this is a plugin or something?

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is **yes**, of course you can use multiple JavaScript libraries on one web page.

The longer answer is that it depends on what exactly those libraries do. I don't know what paper.js does, but here's one example: if, for some reason, paper.js removed everything from the page, including your Processing canvas, then Processing.js wouldn't work correctly.

But it looks like both libraries simply draw to a canvas, so nothing is stopping you from having two canvases on your page and using each library to draw to one.

If you want to use both libraries to draw to the same canvas, then that's more complicated.

Honestly, the best way to answer these questions is to just try something. You probably could have thrown together a little example project and tested this for yourself in the time it took you to get an answer. If you're still confused, I suggest you try asking a more specific question and posting an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

To update Sublime to highlight Paper.js

Go to TOOLS
Command Palette
Type in Package Resource Viewer
Go to "Open Resource"
Then type HTML
Click on "HTML" which will give you a new list that includes, "HTML.sublime-syntax". Select this option.
At the top of the page will read "%YAML 1.2".

Ctrl + F will give you the ability to search for "MIME".

The line you want will look like this:

```
  javascript_mime_type: |-
    (?ix:
      # https://mimesniff.spec.whatwg.org/#javascript-mime-type
      (?:application|text)/(?:x-)?(?:java|ecma)script
      | text/javascript1\.[0-5]
      | text/jscript
      | text/livescript
```

Next, add this line to the bottom:

```
  | text/paperscript
```

The final version should look like this:

```
  javascript_mime_type: |-
    (?ix:
      # https://mimesniff.spec.whatwg.org/#javascript-mime-type
      (?:application|text)/(?:x-)?(?:java|ecma)script
      | text/javascript1\.[0-5]
      | text/jscript
      | text/livescript
      | text/paperscript
    )
```

Ctrl + S is Save and you are finished.